# The command \ESC in Haskell is showing incorrect behavior. How do I resolve this?

Tags: haskell, command-line, io

I'm currently  working through the textbook "Programming in Haskell"
by Graham Hutton (2nd Edition). In his section on the Game of Life, he
defines a function

```
cls :: IO ()
cls = putStr "\ESC[2J"
```

which is supposed to clear the terminal screen when run.

This is not the behavior I'm observing. When I run the code 
the terminal window shows [2J, and is not cleared.

I'm running the code on an HP laptop with windows 10 and using the 
GHC compiler.

Any advice on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's an ansi escape code, not anything to do with Haskell. Looks like the terminal you're using doesn't support them.

Comment: This will only work if the terminal you work in supports ANSI escape codes.

Comment: Apparently you can use the Ubuntu subshell for ANSI terminal support: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#DOS_and_Windows

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice Carl and Willem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a console/terminal program which supports such escape sequences.

On Unix-like systems, like Linux, that's the default.

On windows, the standard console probably does not support them (?). Using a more advanced terminal like [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) should work. I just tried ConEmu on a windows 8 machine and it respected the escape sequence, clearing the screen as wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! I could run the code successfully using ConEmu.